# Meaning of these signs in "Switch Hitter"

Tags: arrested-development

When Tobias is spreading the name "Funke" around the water cooler, some strange signs are posted in the break room of the production company.  Given the nature of the show these have to be some sort of joke or reference, but I can't see it.  They are a little like the Bluths' notes of "Get milk" and so on in the model home, but they don't quite work and no Bluth works there (yet).
[image: Enjoy Your Lunch]

[image: Close Door]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is strange about these. Are you referring to the *Close door* and *Enjoy your lunch* signs? Are they not just... standard office signs?

Comment: Everything in this show means something.  To be that prominent must be a hidden reference.

Comment: Sometimes, the problem with everything on a show meaning something is that when something doesn't mean something, no one can ever believe it. It could mean something. But it could also just be one of a billion standard office signs seen around the world. I'm staring at a "close the door" sign as I type this, which is only two feet removed from the "stop working, take your lunch and enjoy it" sign.

Answer (score 4):

No. **Those are normal signs for a normal workplace.**

- `Close Door` is just a reminder for people to double check that they closed the fridge door right. Likely because it has defrosted from being left halfway open too often.
- `Enjoy your lunch` is typical HR/Office Spirit nonsense.
- `Keep Area Clean` is someone pissed that people leave a mess in the kitchen all the time.

Personally, I've seen similar signs in every break room (and bathrooms, especially open to the public) at any 10-50 people office. When there are more people than that, the offices usually have a corporate lunch room and large bathrooms instead, with cleaning staff so it's less common.

Other signs that are normal:

- No bags in Fridge
- Don't leave Sponge in sink
- Fridge is emptied every Tuesday
- Everything must have a name on it
- To Whomever stole my soda/food/cake

Comment: I don't buy it.  Those are prominently placed, very conspicuous signs, done differently than all the other signs there.

Comment: Have you seen the show? It's got a lot of stuff like this.  For example, on most shows, "Buy milk" on the fridge is totally normal.  But on this show, it's a running gag that you wouldn't notice until the tenth time you've seen the show.

Comment: @thumbtackthief where else would you place a sign to close the fridge door, other than a fridge? When was the last time you were in a small office kitchen/break room?

Comment: When's the last time you watched this show?

Comment: @thumbtackthief google image search `break room passive aggressive signs` for tons of examples. This is normal part of office life.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but this show has a very specific sense of humor which it seems you're not familiar with, so you'll forgive me for not thinking your answer is the correct one.

Comment: @thumbtackthief your overthinking it. Not everything has to have a comedic reason. You may as well ask why that guy is wearing a grey suit, or why she chose to wear a black jacket with a pink shirt.

Comment: OK, thanks for your opinion, but again, if you've never seen the show, your opinion probably is fairly uninformed.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: I don't think this is an uninformed opinion at all. You're demanding an intricate reason for this, because the show is intelligent. But ever very single shot of the series does *not* have some hidden meaning. Many do, yes. But not every, single shot. They'd never have time to actually *film* the show if that was the case! It's hard to consider *any* deeper meaning to this scene. Perhaps the signs are there because they were there in real life. Perhaps they were written by one of the characters. But their actual *meaning* is obvious, so I'm not sure what the mystery here is.

Comment: Maybe.  I just personally wouldn't go around answering questions about a show I hadn't seen, but I guess that's just me.

Comment: I have seen the show. That signs weren't referenced, they weren't a setup to a Facist office worker confrontation, they weren't out of place ***or weird to have in a generic break room*** Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar...

Comment: cde and myself have both seen the show. We just disagree with your analysis, that's all.